# How do I override CSS files in Child Theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

There is a theme that has various CSS files, I created a Child Theme from that theme.

Then I created a new page and add the css file from `functions.php`:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'new-page.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'page-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/page-style.min.css');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

So to override the other CSS files from the main theme for specific elements, I have to use `!important` for each time I want to override them.

Like:

```
selector{
    property1: value !important;
    property2: value !important;
    ..
}
..
```

So is there is a way to include that file at the just before the `</head>` for example or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles(){

        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/page-style.min.css', array('parent-style') );
    }
```

My be using this code in `function.php` will work. By this code `child theme` can access all the `parent theme css` and can add new css & overwrite the parent theme css. And the priority is given to `child theme css` first. so writing `!important` wont be necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Please do not use !important whenever you can, but instead use the **css specifity**.

***EDIT: By using the CSS Specifity it becomes unneccesary to control the load-order of the css files, which btw could be handled different by some browsers or caching plugins...***

General CSS Rules:
An id reference is stronger than a class reference which is stronger than a html element reference.
For example if you have a :

```
<a href="" id="myID" class="myClass">
```

and this css

```
#myID{color:red;}
.myClass{color:blue;}
a{color:black;}
```

The color of the element will be RED

So if the css you want to overwrite has:

```
selector{color:red;}
```

define in your overwrite css:

```
body selector{color:blue;}
```

and this new selector will be automatically stronger than the other one, overwriting the red, and displaying the text in blue. No "!important" needed

now you can make selectors like

```
#MyID.myClass
div > #MyID.myClass
div > #MyID.myClass
a.myClass 
a#MyID.myClass
body article .content #myID.myClass
```

etc.

So the more specific you define your element, the stronger this css definition is over the other ones.

To explain: The CSS specifity defines that the ID selector has e.g. weight 5, class selector weight 3 and html selector weight 1. So by joining them you can make in the same css file new css selectors which have more weight than those defined before, thus making it unnecessary to use the ugly "!important"

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert, but you've got some spelling and punctuation errors, it's usually best to avoid making these kinds of comments and just to fix any issues you can find. Try running your text through a grammar checker for starters. Good luck!

Comment: I didn't know it's about grammary nor that I need to be english teacher to write here, in the end this is not exclusive for english speaking people (or is it?) ;-) the css itself is OK. nevertheless I'll correct the grammary errors as far as I recognize them.